# Sequelize: where query string is in array of strings postgresql

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I am trying to perform a query in `sequelize` where I want to get only users that have the correct role.  Roles are stored as an array of strings.  For example `['student']` or `['school_owner', 'admin']`.

In this particular case, I'm actually trying to get a school and include the school owners for that school.  The failing relevant query is

```
const ownerQuery: { [key: string]: any } = {};
ownerQuery.roles = {$in: ["{school_owner}"]};

School
  .findById(req.params.id,{include: [{ model: User, where: ownerQuery }]})
  .then((school: School | null) => {
    if (school === null) {
      res.status(404).json({message: "Not Found"})
    } else {
      res.json(school)
    }
  }, (error) => next(error))
```

`sequelize` is storing the array values as something like `{school_owner, admin}`.  The [documentation](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html) says that I can use the following instead for my `$in` query

```
ownerQuery.roles = {$in: ["school_owner"]};
```

Which removes the `{}` but it gives me a `Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.'` error.

In the first example, the query doesn't fail, but it doesn't work like an `$in` query either.  I have to match the contents of `roles` exactly. For example, if a user has both `admin` and `school_owner` roles I have to say

```
ownerQuery.roles = {$in: ["{school_owner, admin}"]};
```

What's the correct way to perform an `$in` query so that I can match all users that have a specific roles?

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to implement this functionality is to do the following

```
ownerQuery.roles = { $contains: ["school_owner"] };
```

This will return all users that have a role `school_owner` in their array of `roles`